# Editing the Splash screen - Are Fade in's allowed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Hello
I've created an app, and im just wondering since the default.png splashscreen is pretty boring as it just goes straight into the app, im wondering if im allowed to use transitions, so the splash screens fades into the main view, and my app will still get approved ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've written an app that does a fade in from the default image. It's in the store, so I'll say your probably fine. The only thing I was concerned with originally was this clause from the HIG:

> Avoid displaying an About window or a
>   splash screen. In general, try to
>   avoid providing any type of startup
>   experience that prevents people from
>   using your application immediately.

A strict interpretation could lead to the conclusion that a fade takes longer than directly displaying the main screen, and thus "prevents people from using your application immediately." But there are also plenty of apps in the store that violate the HIG in various ways, and I don't really even view the fade-in as an offense.

Answer (score 2):

We've had applications approved using splash screen fade ins. There are quite a few apps in the store using the technique, Dropbox on iPad and iPhone are two popular apps using animated transitions from the splash screen.

[Dustin Dobervich explains a technique](http://www.dobervich.com/2010/10/22/fade-out-default-ipad-app-image-with-proper-orientation/) for doing so. His example is focuses on iPad, however you can just change the #define constants to get it working on iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I can add another verification that Apple accepts apps with fading intros.

The "No Splashscreen" is a really good idea but very few apps follow it.  If you are working for a client it's almost impossible to talk them out of a spalshscreen.

I think what may work best is a mixture, where you have a hint of your UI integrated into the splashscreen so it seems more natural when the app appears.

Don't forget that in multitasking devices the user will not generally be see the splashscreen...